# Mongoose FilterQuery it's getting mapped to any type

Tags: typescript, mongoose, visual-studio-code, nestjs, nomachine-nx

Im having a problem with typescript system and/or vscode. I currently have a service method that has the following structure.

```
    async find(
        query: FilterQuery<PlaceDocument>,
        options: QueryOptions = {},
    ): Promise<PlaceDocument[]> {
        return this.placeModel.find(query, undefined, options);
    }
```

Both `FilterQuery` and `QueryOptions` come from *`mongoose`*. The issue here is the following.
[image]

I don't have intellisense, don't know what is causing this.

The repo is an nx monorepo using nestjs with mongoose and graphql.